# Null pointer exception in method that calls another method Mockito

Tags: junit, nullpointerexception, mockito, powermockito

I am new to Mockito and Powermockito. I have a class to test which interacts with the database in order find and also delete data from the database through different public methods. The application is typical Java EE application and the The class under test belongs to Service package in Businesslogic. The method which I want to test looks like below :

```
    public List<QuestionDtoWrapper> searchInQuestions(final Integer ID, final Integer catID,
                final String searchString, final String language) {
            final List<QuestionDtoWrapper> result = new ArrayList<>();

//In line below I get null pointer exception although I have stubbed this method            
final List<QuestionDtoInt> questions = facade.findQuestionsByCatTemplate(ID, catID,
                    searchString, language);
            for (final QuestionDtoInt question : questions) {
                result.add(new QuestionDtoWrapper(question));
            }
            Collections.sort(result, new QuestionComparator(new Locale("de")));

            return result;
        }
```

This is how I tried to test the method in my Junit Test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(QuesService.class)

public class QuesServiceTest {  
        @Mock
        QuesFacade mockFbFacade;

        @Mock
        List<QuesDtoInt> questions;

        @Spy
        QuesService myService = new QuesService();

        @Before
         public void setUp() throws Exception {
         MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        }   

        @Test
            public void testSearchInQuestions() throws ParseException {
                PowerMockito.doReturn(questions).when(mockFbFacade).findQuestionsByCatTemplate(anyInt(), anyInt(), anyString(), anyString());
                List<QuestionDtoWrapper> res = null ;
                res = myService.searchInQuestions(anyInt(), anyInt(), anyString(), anyString());
                assertNotNull(res);
            }
```

I am getting Null pointer exception in Line where the method calls another method. See my comment in source code. Could someone please let me know:

1) Am I using mockito for the correct subject ? Should I use real Test data ? But what about the database connections n all ? I tried that approach and ended up using Mockito only.

2) Why am I getting Null pointer exception although I have stubbed that method with Powermockito ?

3) please provide your valuable suggestions to test the given method correctly.

Note:- I am not allowed to do any refactoring in the code.

Comment: You create some mocks but you do not inject them into your `myService`. You should not mock a List (`questions`), instead use a real list.

Comment: Also you probably do not want to use a `spy` here (at least I don't see a reason for that in your snippet). Depending on how your `QuesService` class looks you want to use `@InjectMocks` here. You might want to add more information about your class.

Comment: Why do you try to use `PowerMockito` for this specific case?